# How to add UserControl to message page in Outlook Vsto

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, message

I am writing one add-on for Outlook 2016.
I added and integrated one UserControl page in my Outlook Vsto project
But the only problem is that I want to add my usercontrol page to the new email sending page

```html
         myUserControl = new UserControl();
        CustomTaskPane = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(myUserControl, "Title", "what do I need to write to appear on the message page?" );
          
            myCustomTaskPane.Visible = true;
            myUserControl.Width = 500;
```

what do I need to write to appear on the message page?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an Outlook form region, see [Walkthrough: Design an Outlook form region](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-designing-an-outlook-form-region?view=vs-2019) for more information.

### To add a form region to the Outlook VSTO Add-in project

1. In Solution Explorer, select the Add-In project.
2. On the Project menu, click Add New Item.
3. In the Add New Item dialog box, select Outlook Form Region, name the file, and then click Add.
4. The New Outlook Form Region wizard starts.
5. On the Select how you want to create the form region page, click Design a new form region, and then click Next.
6. On the Select the type of form region you want to create page, click Adjoining, and then click Next.
7. An adjoining form region adds appends the form region to the bottom of an Outlook form's default page. For more information about form region types, see [Create Outlook form regions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/creating-outlook-form-regions?view=vs-2019).
8. On the Supply descriptive text and select your display preferences page, type it in the Name box.
9. Select Inspectors that are in compose mode and then click Next.

On the Identify the message classes that will display this form region page, select Mail Message and then click Finish.